# "Single NSMutableArray" vs. "Multiple C-arrays" --Which is more Efficient/Practical?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, arrays, opengl-es

**Situation:**
I have a DAY structure. The DAY structure has three variables or attributes: a Date (NSString*), a Temperature (float), and a Rainfall (float).

**Problem:**
I will be iterating through an array of about 5000 DAY structures and graphing a portion of these onto the screen of the iPhone device using OpenGL.

**Question:**
As far as drawing performance, which is better? I could simply create an NSMutableArray of DAY structures (NSObjects) and iterate on the array on each draw call -- which I think would be hard on the CPU. Or, I could instead manually manage three different C-Arrays -- One for the Date String (2-Dimensional), One for the temperature (1-Dimensional) and One for the Rainfall (1-Dimensional). I could keep track of the current Day by referencing the current index of the iterated C-Arrays.

Comment: You could also have one C array of the Day struct.  Easier to manage than 3 arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not a lot of work, *always* go with the convenient solution and only optimize when the code proves to be a bottleneck. And if you were going to write a big chunk of code that would take a long time to rewrite into a more optimized version, do a simple test case and profile.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you keeping a date in an NSString object instead of an NSDate object?

Comment: What NSResponder Said.  Given that you have strings representing Dates, there is quite likely a far bigger performance issue in your app that anything related to arrays.  Quantify, then optimize.

Answer (score 2):

Try both and profile.

There's really no other answer, especially since we can never know your *exact* context for sure. Every app works differently.

If they both give the same performance, choose the one that is the easiest for you to use and is the most readable.